# How can I stop clang-format breaking a function call after the parenthesis?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have this function:

```
  return dispatch<ostream &>(date,
                            [&](Date d) -> ostream & { return out << d.year << "-" << d.month << "-" << d.day; },
                            [&](Period p) -> ostream & { return out << p.days << " days"; });
```

I would like it to be formatted this way. Until recently, i was using clang-format-7, which did so. I have upgraded to clang-format-15, which i cannot persuade to format this the same way.

With config like this:

```
Language: Cpp

ColumnLimit: 240
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
```

It comes out like this, with all arguments on a single line, and not aligned with the open bracket, but instead indented:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const AbsoluteOrRelativeDate &date) {
  return dispatch<ostream &>(
      date, [&](Date d) -> ostream & { return out << d.year << "-" << d.month << "-" << d.day; }, [&](Period p) -> ostream & { return out << p.days << " days"; });
}
```

If i lower the column limit:

```
ColumnLimit: 120
```

It comes out much the same, but with another line break:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const AbsoluteOrRelativeDate &date) {
  return dispatch<ostream &>(
      date, [&](Date d) -> ostream & { return out << d.year << "-" << d.month << "-" << d.day; },
      [&](Period p) -> ostream & { return out << p.days << " days"; });
}
```

If i turn off bin-packing:

```
BinPackArguments: false
```

It at least breaks the arguments onto separate lines, but still breaks them from the opening parenthesis, and indents rather than aligning:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const AbsoluteOrRelativeDate &date) {
  return dispatch<ostream &>(
      date,
      [&](Date d) -> ostream & { return out << d.year << "-" << d.month << "-" << d.day; },
      [&](Period p) -> ostream & { return out << p.days << " days"; });
}
```

Adding this:

```
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1000
```

Makes no difference.

Why is clang-format ignoring (most of) the options i give it? How can i get it to format my code the way i want?

Here's [a godbolt with the code](https://godbolt.org/z/3877vdcf4) - there's a bit more in there so it actually compiles. I know the date format is rubbish, this is just a demo!